# i want to compare and obtain new data of 2 files, but the place of the content changes lines

Tags: file, comparison, diff

lest say i have 2 files with the following content:

```
file1.txt

1- cat
2- dog
3- fish
4- lion
```

and the file 2:

```
file2.txt
1- fish
2- lion
3- "new data"
4- cat
5-dog
```

with the methods that I have used, they always interpret the change of line of the content as "new data" even if it is not., how can I ignore that and only obtain the new data?

I took a look at the `difflib` python library but couldn't find anything that refers to that specifically.

Comment: why are each of the other lines considered to be the same? `1- cat` != `1- fish`, `2- dog` != `5-dog`, etc

Comment: one possibility could be to normalise each line (strip parts not used for comparison); for first file add as keys to hash; for second file check if hash key exists. if it doesn't, line is new

Comment: eg: `awk '{ k=$0; gsub(/[0-9]+/,0,k); gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,FS,k); sub(/^0- ?/,_,k); } NR==FNR{a[k];next} !(k in a)' file1 file2`

Comment: wow that's exactly what i need thanks u so much, you have no idea how much that helps me